# Why aren't 3-channel storage types (mostly) color renderable in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I'm having a hard time finding out why some `int` and `unsigned int` internal storage types are "color renderable" and others aren't. A few examples

#### Four channels

| internal storage type | color renderable |
| --- | --- |
| GL_RGBA8 | Y |
| GL_RGBA8I | Y |
| GL_RGBA32UI | Y |

#### Three channels

| internal storage type | color renderable |
| --- | --- |
| GL_RGB8 | Y |
| GL_RGB8I |  |
| GL_RGB32UI |  |
| GL_RGB565 | Y |

#### Two- and one channels

| internal storage type | color renderable |
| --- | --- |
| GL_RG8 | Y |
| GL_RG8UI | Y |
| GL_R8 | Y |
| GL_R8UI | Y |

I understand (I think) why sRGB- and floating-point internal storage types are non-color-renderable, but why are non-normalized, three-channel, `int` and `unsigned int` storage types non-color renderable? Why aren't one- and two-channel `int` and `unsigned int` storage types non-color-renderable too? I read through the applicable parts of the OpenGL ES 3 spec and all it seems to say is 'because it's not marked as "color renderable" in the table'. I think I'm missing something embarrassingly basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general three channel storage types are disliked by hardware, as three is not a power of two and therefore texels/pixels can end up spanning cache lines.

To avoid this, in practice most 3 channel formats will end up being rounded up to a 4 channel internal format with 1 channel of padding.

Just use a 4 channel format, you're no worse off.

Comment: That makes sense. However `RGB8` should the same cache behaviour as `RGB8UI` and `RGB565` has the same as `RGB16UI`. The only difference I can think of is that `RGB8` and `RGB565` are much older and maybe predate modern focus on data-oriented design? Do you know if RGB8 or RGB565 are less performant than better aligned storage formats?

Comment: RGB565 is 16 bits, so is power of 2 aligned.

Comment: ... and RGB8 is likely RGBX8 internally anyway, so really not a 3 component format in practice, even though you think it is.

Comment: The modern trend in graphics APIs is to avoid cases where the driver is effectively lying to the application about what is supported, and to only expose what is efficiently supported. So no three component formats.

Comment: Oh interesting. One final question: do you know what the purpose is of these non-color-renderable internal storage formats? I assume it's useless within the render pipeline.

Comment: You may still be able to specify them as read-only texture formats (which probably then get converted to a 4 component format on upload, with a default value swizzle for the unused component).